# D3.js force graph link values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3 and looking to build a force graph based on this: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8043434

I have a CSV file with the links: how do I generate the link values?

Comment: specify path for the csv file and from the code, it will generate links for you

Comment: // get the data
d3.csv("force.csv", function(error, links) {
 
var nodes = {};
 
// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] || 
        (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
    link.target = nodes[link.target] || 
        (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
    link.value = +link.value;
});